# Android Swipe Gesture Not Reliable

Tags: android, xamarin.android, gesture, swipe, onfling

I have swiping working to some extent but I have a series of textviews and spinners that are on the screen and it seems like if I don't swipe straight across one of them and go just a little across two of them it doesn't pick it up that well. In general I don't think that it is picking up the swipe as good as what happens on the iPhone and I was wondering if anyone could critique my code and help me optimize it.

I'm initializing the GesureDectector and GestureListener. Here is the GestureListener class:

```
    public class GestureListener : Java.Lang.Object, GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener
    {
        private static int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
        private static int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
        private static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
        private View view;
        private Activity act;

        public GestureListener(View _view, Activity _act)
        {
            view = _view;
            act = _act;
        }

        public bool OnDown( MotionEvent e )
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool OnFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY )
        {
            if ( Math.Abs( e1.GetY() - e2.GetY() ) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH ){
                return false;
            }
            if ( e1.GetX() - e2.GetX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY ){
                HandleLeft();               
            }else if ( e2.GetX() - e1.GetX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.Abs( velocityX ) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY ){
                HandleRight();
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void OnLongPress( MotionEvent e )
        {

        }

        public bool OnScroll( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY )
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnShowPress( MotionEvent e )
        {

        }

        public bool OnSingleTapUp( MotionEvent e )
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void HandleLeft(){
            Male currActivity = (Male)act;
            currActivity.GetStrings("Female");
        }

        private void HandleRight(){
            Male currActivity = (Male)act;
            currActivity.GetStrings("Results");
        }
    }
```

I am using this for my OnTouch Event:

```
 public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
     bool handled = false;

     if(flingDetector != null){
    handled = flingDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
     }

     if(v.GetType() == typeof(Spinner)){
    return !handled;    
     }else{
    return handled;
     }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.